# Change mongo data directory for a specific database

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to change the data directory for a specific database in mongo? I'm optimizing a particular database for speed and I would like to move it to an SSD drive. The drive is not large enough to store all other databases in the machine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the path for a specific database, but you can accomplish the same thing at the filesystem level by doing something like this:

1. Run with [directoryPerDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB) enabled (if you are turning this on, make sure that you move your existing data files into the correct folder
2. Let's assume your database is called foo - you now have a folder "foo" that contains all the data files for that database
3. Copy that folder onto your SSD
4. Use a symbolic link/alias to point from your dbpath folder to the new folder on the SSD

Note: On Linux you can also just mount the SSD at `/path/to/dbpath/foo` and then copy the data files to the folder.